# Most efficient way to select a row based on value across multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with four columns to hold anywhere from 1 to 4 userID values.  I.e.  `userid1`, `userid2`, `userid3`, `userid4`

I know I can do this:

```
select * from table where userid=userid1 or userid=userid2 or userid=userid3 or userid=userid4;
```

Will this also work?

```
select * from table where userid in (userid1,userid2,userid3,userid4);
```

I'm wondering if there is a more-efficient method of doing queries like this?  Using merged indexes?  This table could end up being extremely large so any advice on how I should create indexes would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Find records where a known value appears in one or more of 4 columns? Anything else?

Comment: basically that, but the table could get extremely large so I'm wondering what the most efficient way to code such a search would be or if there's any special index that would make it faster to search across 4 columns instead of one.